# How can I extract a vector to sub-vectors which have a continuous range

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector rows as follows:

```
rows=[1 2 3 5 6 7 10 11 12 13 14]
```

I want to extract the vector to some sub-vectors which have a continuous range such as

```
vec1=[1 2 3];
vec2=[5 6 7];
vec3=[10 11 12 13 14];
```

I am using MATLAB to do this task. This is my code. But it looks complex. If you have other way or short MATLAB function. Please let me know

```
for i=1:length(rows)-1
   if((rows(i)+1)==rows(i+1)) %% The different of each element is 1
       index_length=index_length+1;       
   else
       sub_ranges=[sub_ranges index_length];
       index_length=0;
   end
end
%% For last element in rows
if((rows(end-1)+1)==rows(end))
   sub_ranges=[sub_ranges index_length];
   index_length=0;
end
%% Extract for each range
low_bound=0;
high_bound=0;
sub_ranges=sub_ranges+1;
sub_rows_extract=[];
for i=1:length(sub_ranges)-1
    if i==1
        result=rows(1:sub_ranges(i))'
        filename=sprintf('row_%d.mat',i);
        save(filename,'result');
        low_bound=sub_ranges(1)+1;
    else
        high_bound=low_bound+sub_ranges(i)-1;
        result=rows(low_bound:high_bound)'
        low_bound=high_bound+1;
        filename=sprintf('row_%d.mat',i);
        save(filename,'result');
    end
end
```

Comment: Please do *not* create the same question multiple times! I invested time in answering your identical (now deleted) question, without knowing that somebody already solved your problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is some what easier with diff(): you just find where the distance between two entries is bigger than 1. Then split the matrix at these points.

```
rows=[1 2 3 5 6 7 10 11 12 13 14];
drows=[ find(diff(rows)>1) numel(rows)]; 
n_1=1;
nn=1;
res={};
for n=drows
   res{nn}=rows(n_1:n); 
   n_1=n+1;
   nn=nn+1;
end
```

The Result should be a cell array with the subvectors.
There migth be a more elegant way of splitting them... but cant think of one rigth now

Comment: Or just `res = mat2cell(rows, 1, diff([0 find([diff(rows)>1 true])]));`